# How can I find a file by its content on Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-server

How can I find a file by its content on Linux in the command line?

For example, I want to find a file containing the word "helo" on my computer.

Answer (score 24):

Use:

```
grep -lir "helo" /path/to/dir
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a file named grepall in /usr/local/bin/ with following content:

```
find -type f -exec grep -q $1 {} \; -print
```

then you can search for content by use `grepall something`

Comment: That's a lot of typing when you can just grep -r

Comment: With the Command find you can grep recursive through directories and grep in all files.

Answer (score 1):

`egrep -R "hello" /path/to/dir`

Answer (score 1):

Evil way:
  `grep "something" */*/*`

Answer (score 0):

If you're an admin or coder, you might consider [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) instead of the usual `grep`.

`rg helo` for example searches all files in the current working directory (incl. subfolders).

For more detailed information, consult the [guide](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md), the man page or even the code.